# How can I sign in to my VPS/shell account without having to type my password each time?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, shell

How can I sign in to my VPS/shell account without having to type my password each time?  I have tried pasting a shell script including Prolog code but the password doesn't paste properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question.

Set up shell ssh key terminal mac save public key log in - https://www.linode.com/docs/security/authentication/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/ Does ssh key require password? SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase Where is ssh configuration file mac - http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/05/setup-ssh-config-fie/ command-shift-. see invisible finder files, use AirDrop to transfer to new Macs rather than scp or ftp.